# Array formula to fill column based on two or more lookup keys?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

There is a three-column table. Each row in the first two columns makes a unique identifier (but values in the columns separately are not unique). The third column contains a value for each row in the table.

Then there is another three-column table. Each row in the first two columns is a value to lookup in the first table, to fill the third column with the respective value. So I've been trying to come up with an array formula to fill the third column.

- I don't want a script for the solution, only formula
- I don't want a one-row formula to distribute, only an array formula

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E1:E10&F1:F10; {A1:A10&B1B:10, C1:C10}; 2; 0)))
```

where columns A, B, C are the first table and columns E, F, G are the second table.

Comment: Combining two columns into one, of course! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here using vlookup, query, arrayformula and others to get summing data, with assumption, A21 to B25 as unique master, I16 to K19 is the distribution data with I16 to J19 are unique master from A21 to B25, if the data different with my assumption, change them actually:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(arrayformula(len({A21:A25}) & ":" & len ({B21:B25}) & ":" & {A21:A25} & {B21:B25}),query({arrayformula(len({I16:I19}) & ":" & len ({J16:J19}) & ":" & {I16:I19} & {J16:J19}),arrayformula(if(isnumber(K16:K19),K16:K19,0))},"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1"),2,false))
```

I combine two column with identifier length of each column and colon, because I hope my column combination is right unique, if I combine 'aaa' & 'aaaa' will same with 'aaaa' & 'aaa' but it can be omitted if necessary to shorten the formula:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(arrayformula({A21:A25} & {B21:B25}), query({arrayformula( & {I16:I19} & {J16:J19}), arrayformula(if(isnumber(K16:K19), K16:K19, 0))}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1"),2,false))
```